# Populating table with Javascript object

Tags: javascript, html, json, html-table

I've tried to look into other posts but no one helped me the way I want.
I'm building a table and i need to populate it with some data. Here is my data (or part of it):

```
 var vistorias = [
        { data: '15/05/2015', cliente: 'Viceri', prestador: 'Joaquim', tipo: 'Empresarial simples', empresaPrestadora: 'VistGroup', parecer: 'Bom' },
        { data: '10/05/2015', cliente: 'Krupp', prestador: 'Rafael', tipo: 'Maquinas', empresaPrestadora: 'Vistoriers', parecer: 'Execelente' },
        { data: '24/03/2015', cliente: 'Itautec', prestador: 'Thiago', tipo: 'Empresarial simples', empresaPrestadora: 'VistGroup', parecer: 'Bom' }];
```

And here is my table:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="sample_1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Data
            </th>
            <th>
                Cliente
            </th>
            <th>
                Prestador
            </th>
            <th>
                Tipo
            </th>
            <th>
                Empresa Prestadora
            </th>
            <th>
                Parecer da Vistoria
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="TabelaVistorias"></tbody>
</table>
```

and here is the code I'm trying to use now:

```
$.each(vistorias, function (vistorias) {
            var nTr = "<tr>"
            nTr += "<td><p>" + vistorias[0] + "</p></td>";
            nTr += "<td><p>" + vistorias[1] + "</p></td>";
            nTr += "<td><p>" + vistorias[2] + "</p></td>";
            nTr += "<td><p>" + vistorias[3] + "</p></td>";
            nTr += "<td><p>" + vistorias[4] + "</p></td>";
            nTr += "<td><p>" + vistorias[5] + "</p></td>";
            nTr += "</tr>";

            $(nTr).appendTo('#TabelaVistorias');
        });
```

they're all (the data and the JS code) inside a `$Doc.ready`.
I know it's simple but I can't manage to do it.

Comment: What is expected result of `vistorias[0]` ? `Properties of object at `vistorias[0]` not appear iterated within `$.each()` ?

Comment: I think vistorias is an object, thus you should use vistorias.data except for [0] etc. But I'm not sure (so no hate).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `$each` callback function first parameter must be `index` and second is `object`

```
 $.each(vistorias, function (index, v) {
        var nTr = "<tr>"
        nTr += "<td><p>" + v.data + "</p></td>";
        nTr += "<td><p>" + v.cliente + "</p></td>";
        nTr += "<td><p>" + v.prestador + "</p></td>";
        nTr += "<td><p>" + v.tipo + "</p></td>";
        nTr += "<td><p>" + v.empresaPrestadora + "</p></td>";
        nTr += "<td><p>" + v.parecer + "</p></td>";
        nTr += "</tr>";

        $(nTr).appendTo('#TabelaVistorias');
    });
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/03cngm45/)

Comment: i've done exaclty as your Fiddle, but it doesn't work for me :/ it simply don't populate. I'm going to check if it have everything i need for it to work

Answer (score 0):

With each the arguments are index and the value of the current index. You are using the index as an array whould makes no sense. You need to use the second argument and you need to reference the keys on the object.

```
$.each(vistorias, function (ind, obj) {
    var nTr = "<tr>"
    nTr += "<td><p>" + obj.data + "</p></td>";
    nTr += "<td><p>" + obj.cliente + "</p></td>";
    /* and do the rest */
    $(nTr).appendTo('#TabelaVistorias');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is you are trying to access the objects inside the array as if they were arrays. You also have the parameters for the callback incorrect. Try this:

```
$.each(vistorias, function (index, vistoria) {
        var nTr = "<tr>"
        nTr += "<td><p>" + vistoria.data + "</p></td>";
        nTr += "<td><p>" + vistoria.cliente + "</p></td>";
        nTr += "<td><p>" + vistoria.prestador + "</p></td>";
        nTr += "<td><p>" + vistoria.tipo + "</p></td>";
        nTr += "<td><p>" + vistoria.empresaPrestadora + "</p></td>";
        nTr += "<td><p>" + vistoria.parecer + "</p></td>";
        nTr += "</tr>";

        $(nTr).appendTo('#TabelaVistorias');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

`$.each(vistorias, function (vistorias)`

Try adjusting parameter names to be unique , or different from variable name of original array or object . `vistorias` at `function (vistorias)` would be index , or key of array or object ; not object itself . Second parameter to `$.each()` would be value , or object property.

> [jQuery.each( array, callback )](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/#jQuery-each-array-callback)
>
> **array**
>
> Type: Array
>
> The array to iterate over.
>
> **callback**
>
> Type: Function( Integer indexInArray, Object value )
>
> The function that will be executed on every object.

---

Try using nested `$.each()` on objects iterated within initial `$.each()`

```
var tbody = $("#TabelaVistorias");

$.each(vistorias, function(key, value) {
  var tr = $("<tr />");
  $.each(value, function(k, v) {
    $("<td />", {
      html: "<p>" + v + "</p>"
    }).appendTo(tr)
  });
  tbody.append(tr)
})
```

```js
var vistorias = [{
  data: '15/05/2015',
  cliente: 'Viceri',
  prestador: 'Joaquim',
  tipo: 'Empresarial simples',
  empresaPrestadora: 'VistGroup',
  parecer: 'Bom'
}, {
  data: '10/05/2015',
  cliente: 'Krupp',
  prestador: 'Rafael',
  tipo: 'Maquinas',
  empresaPrestadora: 'Vistoriers',
  parecer: 'Execelente'
}, {
  data: '24/03/2015',
  cliente: 'Itautec',
  prestador: 'Thiago',
  tipo: 'Empresarial simples',
  empresaPrestadora: 'VistGroup',
  parecer: 'Bom'
}];

var tbody = $("#TabelaVistorias");

$.each(vistorias, function(key, value) {
  var tr = $("<tr />");
  $.each(value, function(k, v) {
    $("<td />", {
      html: "<p>" + v + "</p>"
    }).appendTo(tr)
  });
  tbody.append(tr)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="sample_1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Data
      </th>
      <th>
        Cliente
      </th>
      <th>
        Prestador
      </th>
      <th>
        Tipo
      </th>
      <th>
        Empresa Prestadora
      </th>
      <th>
        Parecer da Vistoria
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="TabelaVistorias"></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: As much as I hate each the simplicity of your solution, although in my opinion a bit unreadable to any novice, is quite lovely. =]